# How to send push message through GCM/Firebase to an android device using boto3 client publish (AWS SNS)

Tags: android, boto3, amazon-sns

Sending the push message through the AWS Management Console works just fine using the `JSON message generator`. But whenever i call the `publish()` function, the message never reaches the phone.

Publishing to iOS works just fine like so:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sns', region_name=REGION_NAME)
client.publish(TargetArn=SOME_VALID_ARN, Message='This message gets pushed to iOS')
```

Doing this with GCM/Firebase endpoints just does not work. I tried an ridiculous amount of `json.dumps()` or manual quotation mark escaping combinations.

I hope this question saves someone some time and frustration.

Answer (score 5):

The publish call that actually works needs **TWO** nested `json.dumps`:

```
client.publish(TargetArn=ARN, MessageStructure='json', Message=json.dumps({'GCM': json.dumps('This finally gets delivered to Android')}))
```

First of all, [the boto3 SNS documentation of the publish() function](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.publish) is pretty confusing:

> If you want to send the same message to **all transport protocols**, include the text of the message as a String value.

Wrong, GCM, a transport protocol that nearly all android devices use, does not work this way! Maybe this should be mentioned.

> If you want to send different messages for each transport protocol, set the value of the MessageStructure parameter to json **and use a JSON object for the Message parameter**.

No, you can't use a JSON object for the Message parameter. The parameter still needs to be a string object. But it needs to contain parsable JSON. This should be reworded.

> the value of the Message parameter must:
>
> - be a syntactically valid JSON object; and
> - contain at least a top-level JSON key of "default" with a value that is a string.

Neither point is true.

Also, the fact that you need another `json.dumps()` within the JSON object is mentioned nowhere. A simple example like the one above would have helped wonders in that documentation.